# All Categories with filter

Tags: category, filter, category-tree, sort

I have searched many time for this problem, but I have not found a solution for this feature. I will show all available categories from specific store view as a list on a single page. The feature now, I need a filter for this list like [this page](http://www.ikea.com/de/de/catalog/allproducts/) e.g. Order by ASC and Order by categories.

Have anyone a answer or a solution for me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Arunendra said with the active filter you can go through them

This would get you all categories with a link to the category

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added this to a page but i  became this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function load() on unknown in...on line 75

Comment: Updated it please try again

Comment: Mmh, now i became magento error page and this message: Invalid method Varien_Data_Tree_Node::load(Array
(
    [0] => 157
)
)

Comment: ok new try :)..

Comment: Great at least finally it works

Comment: Is there a way to exclude specific categories from this loop?

Comment: A quick and dirty way would be to exclude the categories if you know their ID and just skip it with an if clause for these.

Comment: Ok, i have test it with filter but this works only for ->getCollection and not for ->getStoreCategories().

Answer (score 0):

Categories in magento doesn't have to Store relations ( because its used by stores ( store can point to subcategory as its root category for instance ) etc.. ) So any category you create it will be visible in all stores.

But is has attribute is_active ( which is store view scope ).

So to get the categories in specific store ( you need to make sure its not active in other stores )

and Filter with the attribute

```
->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
```

Hope this help you.